# while loop never ends while printing a diamond

Tags: c, design-patterns

i am still trying to get familier with patterns
in order to print a diamond i made the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
//a Program to print a solid diamond
int main(){
    int i,n,j,k,first,second, rows,space;
    printf("Enter value of n : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    space= rows-1;

            for (first=1; first<= rows; first++)
            {
                for(j=1; j<space; j++,n=0)
                    {
                printf(" ");
                }
                space --;
                while (n !=2*first-1)
                {
                    printf("*");
                    ++n;
                }
                printf("\n");

            }
            space= rows;
           //printf("space %i",&space);
            for (second=rows; second>= 1; second--)
            {
                for(j=space; j>1; j--,k=rows)
                    {
                printf(" ");
                    }
 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> endless loop appear <<<<<<<<<<<
                while (k !=2*second-1) 
                {
                    printf("*");
                    ++k;
                }
                printf("\n");

            }
 return 0;
}
```

while debuggin i find out that line 32 is where the problem lies
but can't figure out why though
i apperciate the help

Comment: When you enter the loop, what is the value of `second`? And what is the value of `k`? Will `k` ever be equal to `2 * second - 1` (when the loop is supposed to end)?

Comment: By the way, if the loop `for(j=space; j>1; j--,k=rows)` never iterates (the condition `j > 1` is true immediately) then the value of `k` will be *indeterminate* as it will never be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

When you compile, make sure you have warnings turned on, then heed any suggestions they provide.  On my system, the following were generated:

```
  warning: unused variable 'i' 
  warning: variable 'k' may be uninitialized when used here 
  note: initialize the variable 'k' to silence this warning
  warning: variable 'n' may be uninitialized when used here 
  note: initialize the variable 'n' to silence this warning
```

In this case, `k` not being initialized will likely influence whether or not your loop is infinite.   `n` is also indeterminate.   Initialize all variables as a matter of habit.